# Program which runs other program - different directories & DLLs files

Tags: dll, directory

I'm writing a program and I have problem with running it in the nice way. I use a lot of DLLs and unfortunately they have to be placed in the application directory or in the system folder. I don't want to put it in the system directories and that's why I need to put it in the same directory as my .exe file. Still I don't want the user to look thorugh many many DLLs files to find the .exe. That's why I thought that I could run the .exe with the use of different program which is located in different place(in the same directory as the folder with my .exe and DLL files). Unfortunately, the program loads files only from the directory of the first program. Here's my code. I would be really grateful if you could help me.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>


std::string ExePath()
{
    char buffer[MAX_PATH];
    GetModuleFileName( NULL, buffer, MAX_PATH );
    std::string::size_type pos = std::string( buffer ).find_last_of( "\\/" );
    return std::string( buffer ).substr( 0, pos);
}

int main()
{
    const char * filepath;
    filepath = (ExePath()+"\\bin\\test.exe").c_str();
    STARTUPINFO info={sizeof(info)};
    PROCESS_INFORMATION processInfo;
    if (CreateProcess(filepath, "cmd", NULL, NULL, TRUE, 0, NULL, NULL, &info, &processInfo))
    {
        ::WaitForSingleObject(processInfo.hProcess, INFINITE);
        CloseHandle(processInfo.hProcess);
        CloseHandle(processInfo.hThread);
    }
    return 0;   
}
```

Comment: Why not add additional include paths to the directory you want to host the DLLs?

Comment: Could you tell me how to do it? I have no idea how. I was trying to use the SetDllDirectory() function but the compiler showed: error: 'SetDllDirectory' was not declared in this scope 
It's strange because I included windows.h....